# Display single result on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I get only 1 one result using this code? I am trying to count how many times we can find each 'double' in the table. There is nothing wrong with the db connection, It only gets duplicated values as result. Thank you.

```
The output should be like

    DOUBLE       COUNT
    01 02          10 (as example)
    03 04          12 (as example)

    I am getting duplicated like...

    01 02          10 (as example)
    01 02          10 (as example)


<?php

if ($check == 'doubles'){

   sort($doubles);

   foreach ($doubles as $double) {

        explode(" ", $double);

        $dn1 = $double[0].$double[1];
        $dn2 = $double[2].$double[3];

if ($stmt = $post_con->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT FROM tb WHERE CONCAT(" ", res, " ") LIKE CONCAT("% ", ?, " %") AND CONCAT(" ", res, " ") LIKE CONCAT("% ", ?, " %")')) {

       $stmt->bind_param("ss", $dn1, $dn2);

       $dn1 = sprintf('%02d', $dn1);
       $dn2 = sprintf('%02d', $dn2);

       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->store_result();
       $qty = $stmt->num_rows;

       echo '<div class="mini">'.$dn1.'</div>';
       echo '<div class="mini">'.$dn2.'</div>';
       echo '<div class="n-sort">'.$qty.'</div>';


        }


}
?>
```

Comment: I guess you are missing a tag, php may be

Comment: The code works fine. I only get duplicated values. Thanks @ImranAli

Comment: Could you explain what you try select?

Comment: I've just updated the question. Thanks @AdamSilenko

Comment: can you post example data of tb?

Comment: Sorry there is nothing with mysql. It is ARRAY problem. But I still didn't find the answer . Thanks guys!

Comment: This is very strange solution, i don't know why you return all row only for count it. It is strange that you detect duplicates before "query count" etc....

Comment: Can you show a `$double` array sample?

Comment: I have just updated the question @fusion3k.

Comment: The doubles comes from a php combination of X numbers. That's why it is not supposed to has any repeated rows. Thanks @AdamSilenko Ps. the combination code works fine.

Comment: So, `$double` is an enumerated array with values like "00 00"?

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks @fusion3k

Comment: I am trying to count how many times a each double 00 00 appears in a column of six 00 00 00 00 00 00. In case guys have any better solution for my code. Thanks !

Comment: This code works fine for singles numbers 00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to match exactly your problem, because we don't know your table structure (`res` field content, in particular), but surely I think that there is a problem in this part of code:

```
explode(" ", $double);

$dn1 = $double[0].$double[1];
$dn2 = $double[2].$double[3];
```

When `$double` assume the value of `01 02`, you explode it in `['01','02']`, but you don't capture exploded array.

Then, you use a syntax that is not compatible both with exploded array and with original string. After concatenation, you have this result:

```
$double = '01 02';
# index >  01234
$dn1 = '01';
$dn2 = ' 0';
```

Replace original code in this way:

```
$exploded = explode(" ", $double);
$dn1 = $exploded[0];
$dn2 = $exploded[1];
```

Or in this way:

```
explode(" ", $double);
$dn1 = $double[0].$double[1];
$dn2 = $double[3].$double[4];
```

Comment: res column structure as 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: It works ($dn1 = $exploded[0]; $dn2 = $exploded[1];) Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

to count duplicates try use this query :

```
SELECT count(1) FROM (
SELECT res, Count(1)
FROM tb 
WHERE CONCAT(" ", res, " ") LIKE CONCAT("% ", ?, " %") --I don't know did you need this conditions... 
AND CONCAT(" ", res, " ") LIKE CONCAT("% ", ?, " %")
GROUP BY res
HAVING Count(1) > 1)
```

EDIT:
if you try list duplicates then:

```
SELECT res, Count(1)
FROM tb 
WHERE CONCAT(" ", res, " ") LIKE CONCAT("% ", ?, " %") --I don't know did you need this conditions... 
AND CONCAT(" ", res, " ") LIKE CONCAT("% ", ?, " %")
GROUP BY res
HAVING Count(1) > 1
```

Comment: Sorry there is nothing with mysql. It is ARRAY problem. Thanks @Adam!

Answer (score 0):

Using `distinct` will return all distinct rows in an entire table, but if there are multiple unique rows, then each row will be returned.

What you want is to use an aggregate function like `COUNT(*)` to count the number of rows that match your criteria.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM tb 
WHERE 
    CONCAT(" ", res, " ") LIKE CONCAT("% ", ?, " %") AND 
    CONCAT(" ", res, " ") LIKE CONCAT("% ", ?, " %")
```

This will return the number of rows that match your WHERE conditions.

If you want to find our how many times each double value is in the table, you could group by the double value and count each group. For example:

```
SELECT 
    res,
    COUNT(*) 
FROM tb 
GROUP BY
    res
```

It's difficult for me to answer this question because I am not sure what fields are in your table, what res is, and where the double value you are interested in comes into play.

Comment: Sorry there is nothing with mysql. It is ARRAY problem. Thanks @Peter!